# Not hyphenated but justify alignment

Tags: hyphenation, book-class

Can we remove the hyphenation of the document  without re-paraphrase the sentences, but the alignment still justified, just like when we use justify alignment on Micr•s•ft W•rd?

The reason i'm asking this question is when i saw the LaTeX document using `\documentclass{laporan3}` "laporan" means "report" in English. I don't see babel package on it and somehow the alignment is very neat and fully justified. Btw it used `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` this is the output: [fully justified without hyphenation](https://ibb.co/pP3pb7D), and if i remove that package, the document would be hyphenated. See : [Fully justified but with hyphenation](https://ibb.co/8NxJcPP)

And my point is i don't want to use that document class, and i want to apply that on the book class. This is what happen when i use that on the `book-class`, [Not justified Image](https://ibb.co/0qMpsHC).

Here is the difference:

1. [book-class](https://ibb.co/hCcFrs9)
2. [laporan3class](https://ibb.co/Z82TsdK)

Do you have an idea to do this? Thanks.

My goal: Fully justified, without hyphenation, on the book-class.

Comment: Is this useful `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` to you?

Comment: @MadyYuvi on laporan3class yes, on bookclass no. Since i'm using bookclass and there are some reasons i'm not using laporan3class, it's doesn't affect anything. That package i mean

Comment: Sorry, I missed to mention about to include `\begin{sloppypar}` ... `\end{sloppypar}`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments you think that `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` doesn't work for the `book` class, but it does. But of course it is generally not possible to do decent linebreaking if you don't allow hyphenation, so you also need to tell LaTeX to accept making something really ugly. Here is an example document doing that. It uses a small papersize just to make it harder to break the lines.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy % accept really ugly paragraphs

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. It's really work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Now just don't tell people it is LaTeX you have used to make such ugly documents! :-)